# Problem in finding out most probable number of success in an n-Bernoulli trial.

Tags: probability

How to find out most probable number of success in an n Bernoulli trial if the probability of  success be p.
Please help me.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Mode_and_median

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Show that for $0 < x < n$, $$\dfrac{\mathbb P(X = x+1)}{\mathbb P(X=x)} = \dfrac{p(n-x)}{(1-p)(x+1)}$$
How does that compare to $1$?

Comment: I dont understand what you tried to mention.Please share some concept regarding this event that will help me to understand the matter more cleary.

Comment: What don't you understand about it?  The most probable number of successes is the least integer $x$ for which $\mathbb P(X=x+1)/\mathbb P(X=x) < 1$.

Comment: Why is it so? Please explain.